# How to prevent InfiniteScroll changing queryparams in URL

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I am using Infinite Scroll from Metafizzy on a page which consists of images and are filtered using dropdowns. The JS for Infinite Scrolls is the following. The infinite scrolling works as expected

```
if (document.querySelector('.pagination__next')) {
    let infScroll = new InfiniteScroll('.article-feed', {
        path: '.pagination__next',
        append: '.article',
        hideNav: '.pagination'
    });
}
```

By default, after clicking on any of these filters I get the following queryparams in my URL:

```
?sort=date&collection=&bids=&search=
```

However as I continue to scroll down and the next page is loaded, my queryparams change to the following:

```
?page=1&sort=date
```

How can i ensure the same queryparams are shown, and only the page is changed? The only time I want the queryparams to change is when the user interacts with the filters mentioned.

Comment: Did you get yourself a solution? I've the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't, I ended up rebuilding the website shortly after using React.